# Renderbug Chrome (36 on OS X) on Javascript animation/CSS transition

Tags: jquery, css, macos, google-chrome, transition

I'm creating a website with a simple toggle button to show some paragraphs. You can find a simplified version of it [here in this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/javasluud/4rcqpL57/). In Chrome 36 on OS X [this happens when I toggle the button](http://www.luudjacobs.nl/supergeheim/bug.gif) (don't mind the flashing on the right side, it's about the border on the left).

I'm toggling the content with jQuery (`.slideUp()` and `.slideDown()`) But it also happens when I use `transition: height` in CSS. As you can see in [this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/javasluud/4rcqpL57/1/).

I've already tried to implement a 3d transform, without effects unfortunately.

The problem doesn't occur in other browsers on OS X (Safari, Firefox and Opera) as far as I could tell.

Has anyone else encountered this problem (maybe in another browser)? Me Googling for it resulted in nothing useful. And does someone maybe have another possible solution for it. I'm quite stuck on this problem now.

Thanks!

Comment: It may be OS X specific, I'd go to Chromium issue tracker and ask there.

Comment: @Klaster_1: Thanks for the tip. After digging through the issues there I found it and it seems to be fixed in their latest build.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a Chrome bug happening only in certain builds. They've already fixed it in their latest build. [Chromium issuetracker link](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=395553)